# Extracting data from a script using XPath

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I do not manage to extract the thumbnail link with xpath in the following script/json:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"VideoObject","name":"XYZ","description":"Text","thumbnailUrl":"https://www.thumbnail.com/thumb.jpg","uploadDate":"2000-01-01","contentUrl":"https://www.example.com"}</script>
```

I need the thumbnail link (https://www.thumbnail.com/thumb.jpg) after "thumbnailUrl", but do not know how the selector would follow after

//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/...

Please help.

Comment: If your XPath processor supports XPath 3.1, then `parse-json(//script[@type="application/ld+json"])?thumbnailUrl` would do.

Answer (score 2):

when the you have a file name "script.html" with the content:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"VideoObject","name":"XYZ","description":"Text","thumbnailUrl":"https://www.thumbnail.com/thumb.jpg","uploadDate":"2000-01-01","contentUrl":"https://www.example.com"}</script>
```

then:

```
xidel -s -e "//script[1]"  script.html  >temp.json
xidel -s -e '$json."thumbnailUrl"' temp.json
```

should output:

```
https://www.thumbnail.com/thumb.jpg
```

tested with: `Xidel 0.9.8` (on Windows)

EDIT:

It is also possible in one step

```
xidel -s -e "json(//script)/thumbnailUrl"  script.html
```

Comment: There's no need for a temporary file when you can do: `xidel -s input.htm -e "json(//script[@type='application/ld+json'])/thumbnailUrl"`. And for the latest `xidel` release that's [`parse-json()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-parse-json).

Comment: @Reino: I was not able to get an example using `parse-json()` working. Probablu because of the mixed html/json

Comment: `parse-json()` will only work with [v0.9.9](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/).